# Datetime-local not working with firebase-database

Tags: html, angularjs, datetime, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to insert 4 values into my firebase-database (Equipment, Type, start of downtime and end of downtime). The start and end of downtime values are in datetime-local. When I try inserting the values it only makes nodes for the first 2 values being equipment and type. I don't know why its not inserting the datetime-local values.

**MY HTML**

```
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">

    <div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3" id="equipList">
      <label for="selectequ">Select Equipment</label>
       <select class="form-control" id="selectequ" data-ng-model="equipment" 
          >
        <option data-ng-repeat="eq in allEquipments" >{{eq}}</option>
      </select>

        {{equipment}}
    </div>

        <div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xs-offset-3" id="Type">
         <label for="searchType">Search by Type:</label>
         <select class="form-control" id="searchType" data-ng-model="type">
            <option value="" disabled="" selected="" style="display: none">Select type of maintenance</option>
            <option>Corrective Maintenance</option>
            <option>Preventive Maintenance</option>
            <option>Standby</option>
         </select>
      </div>

        {{type}}

    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">

    <div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3">
      <label for="date">Start of Downtime</label>
        <input type="datetime-local" class="form-control" placeholder="Day, Month, Year" data-ng-model="startDT"/>
    </div>
        {{startDT}}
    <div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3">
      <label for="date">End of Downtime</label>
        <input type="datetime-local" class="form-control" placeholder="Day, Month, Year" data-ng-model="endDT"/>
    </div>

    {{endDT}}

    </div>

<div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6" id="central">
            <a class="btn cd-add-to-cart cd-add-to-cart:hover cd-add-to-cart:active" role="button" data-ng-click="manageDowntime()">MANAGE   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-tasks"></span></a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**MY ANGULARJS**

```
    /*global angular*/
var app = angular.module('downtime', ['ngRoute', 'firebase']);

app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    'use strict';
    $routeProvider.when('/downtime', {
        templateUrl: 'downtime/downtime.html',
        controller: 'downtimeCtrl'
    });
}]);

app.controller('downtimeCtrl', ['$scope', '$firebaseObject', '$firebaseArray', function ($scope, $firebaseObject, $firebaseArray) {
    'use strict';

     $scope.allEquipments = [];
     $scope.allSystems = [];

    $scope.manageDowntime = function () {
        var doesExist = false;
        angular.forEach ($scope.data , function (d) {
        angular.forEach (d.equipments, function (e) {
        })
    });
        firebase.database().ref('downtime/' + $scope.equipment + '/downtime').child($scope.equipment).set({
            equipment: $scope.equipment,
            type : $scope.type,
            start: $scope.startDT,
            end: $scope.endDT
        });
};

    var ref = firebase.database().ref();
        var data = ref.child("data");
        var list = $firebaseArray(data);

        list.$loaded().then(function(data) {
            $scope.data = data;
            angular.forEach ($scope.data , function (d) {

              $scope.allSystems.push(d.$id);  

                angular.forEach (d.equipments, function (e) {
                    $scope.allEquipments.push(e.equipment);
                    console.log($scope.allEquipments);
                })
            });
            console.log($scope.data);
        }).catch(function(error) {
            $scope.error = error;
        });


}]);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope firebase doesn't accept date as datatype. So it converts them as string and store as datetime-local values. [See this documentation for datatypes accepted in set method](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/firebase/set.html).

```
object, array, string, number, boolean, or null // these are the datatypes which firebase will accept.
```

Step 1:

```
store them as datetime-local values in firebase, while retrieving the data, push the date object.

var start_end=new Date(start);
//you will get date object, you can append this to input type date if you wish.
```